# How to call a variable from another class specifically a scnscene to an skoverlay scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scene

```
class AppScene: SCNScene {
    static var targetNode: SCNLookAtConstraint

    override init() {
        super.init()
        //other code not shown...
    }
}
```

So this is my current AppScene class and I am trying to be able to make this variable public to be able to use it in other classes. Specifically to call a button press in my `SKOverlay` Scene and make it do something in my `SCNScene`. However the error shows

```
'static var' declaration requires an initializer expression or getter/setter specifier
```

My guess is that I must have a method the return the variable that is called `returnTargetNode`.

Answer (score 0):

Make this var an optional

```
static var targetNode: SCNLookAtConstraint?
```

Or give it a value (a default value/ a value at the init..)

Comment: Ok that works so thank you! However when I try to do the same with an SCNNode `static var testNode: SCNNode?` when i try to declare a property such as

Comment: `testNode.camera = SCNCamera()`, then it gives me an error such as `BAD INSTRUCTION` and when it unwraps the variable it returns null